# odoo - calendar view with popup form

Tags: calendar, popup, odoo

I`m trying to create calendar with popup form

```
    <record id="view_sale_order_lines_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.line.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <calendar string="Transfers" **event_open_popup="True"** color="state" date_start="date_start" date_stop="date_stop">
                <field name="order_id"/>
                <field name="departure_bcs"/>
                <field name="destination_bcs"/>
                <field name="state"/>
            </calendar>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I cant find any documentation, and for example take code of Meetings Calendar

When i click on calendar line i get popup window with next error:

```
 AccessError No value found for sale.order.line('58',).name
```

ODOO 8.0.1

Comment: Do you want the calendar view to pop up like form???? Did you try using wizard??? @Aleksandr

Answer (score 0):

You must use `event_open_popup="%(my_module.my_form_view)s"`